# android onclick of button how to save custom checkbox state in sharedpreference and get it after app restart

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a listview of all install app. I am using custom adapter now issue is this I want to save the state of my checkboxes (checked or unchecked) when user exits the application so that I can reload this state when the application restarts. Here is my code

```
public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
    private PackageManager mPackManager;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    CheckBox checkBox;
    boolean index[];
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    public Listadapter(Context applicationContext, List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplication, PackageManager packageManager) {
        //super(applicationContext,textViewResourceId,installedApplication);
            super();
            this.mContext = applicationContext;
            this.mListAppInfo = installedApplication;
            index = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
            this.mPackManager = packageManager;
            for (int i = 0; i < installedApplication.size(); i++) {
            checkList.add(false);
            itemChecked = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
            }
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivAppIcon;
        TextView tvAppName;
        TextView tvPkgName;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
        //return ((null != mListAppInfo) ? mListAppInfo.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
       // index = new boolean[mListAppInfo.size()];
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the selected entry

        final ViewHolder holder;

      //  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
        // reference to convertView
            holder.tvAppName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.tvPkgName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.ivAppIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            // holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        }
             else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
        final ApplicationInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        holder.ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        holder.tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
        holder.tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);


        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked())
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                else
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

here is my mainactivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ListView apps;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    ArrayList<String> checkedValue;
    Button bt1;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareAction;
    ApplicationInfo pi = new ApplicationInfo();
    public static final String PREF_PROFILE3 = "pref_profile3";
    public static final String PROFILE3 = "profile3";
    Context context = this;
    SharedPreferences pkg;
    CheckBox cb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        needPermissionForBlocking(context);

        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        apps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        apps.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        checkedValue = new ArrayList<String>();

        Listadapter Adapter = new Listadapter(this, Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this), packageManager);

        apps.setAdapter(Adapter);
        apps.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "all" + checkedValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        pi = (ApplicationInfo) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        cb.performClick();
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue.add(tv.getText().toString());

        } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue.remove(tv.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

in my mainactivity I have a button I want when I check the checkbox and click on button its save the all checkbox state and reload the state when activity open.

Comment: you can update your data in db while checkbox states changed and get data from db with checkbox states.

Comment: @SohailZahid i just want to save checkbox state not all data will you please tell me with sharedprefrences how to made it?

Comment: yes only update checkbox value in db example checked bit 1 and unchecked bit 0 by default value 0 all unchecked.

Comment: preferences save one value against one key how many keys you will create and how you track them so for mature solution use db approach.

Comment: can i use boolean array? sharedprefrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(getString("YOUR_APP_NAME"), MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putBoolean("checkbox_" + CHECKBOX_INDEX, CHECKBOX_IS_CHECKED);
edit.commit();

/* ----- after ----- */
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(getString("YOUR_APP_NAME"), MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.getBoolean("checkbox_" + CHECKBOX_INDEX, false);
```

I think this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) will help you to improve your android skills

add method to Listadapter

```
public void setItemChecked(boolean[] items) {
   itemChecked = items;
}
```

and call this method from your MainActivity with this code

```
boolean[] items = new boolean[Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this).size()];
for (int i = 0; i < Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this).size(); ++i) {
    items[i] = preferences.getBoolean("checkbox_" + i,false);
}
```

and after

```
Listadapter Adapter = new Listadapter(this, Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this), packageManager);
```

call this

```
Adapter.setItemChecked(items);
```

Comment: i know about sharedprefrences but issue is this here is custom checkbox . i dont know how to save it in sharedprefrences and get will you please edit my code

Comment: sure please wait little bit

Comment: please tell me next what should i do?

Comment: how can i send string to activity like i want to save the package name also and now how to get it?

Comment: when you create your Intent for activity call yourIntent.pusString("KEY", "YOUR_STRING");
add this line

Answer (score 0):

checkbox's listener is that:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });
```